# Django - Could not find source to reload

Tags: python, django, pydev

I'm currently using *LiClipe* with *PyDev* to debug my project.

I have a separate module which sits in the core directory of my Django project.

While the project is running in Debug mode I'm able to edit code, save it and then get a confirmation that it is working in the console.

However when I edit this particular module I get the following issue which I'm not sure how to approach:

```
pydev debugger: Start reloading module: "pspotter" ... 
pydev debugger: Could not find source to reload (mod: pspotter)
pydev debugger: reload finished
```

Furthermore the code doesn't seem to be running as it's using *apscheduler*.

**Am I meant to reference this file from somewhere else?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version, when you're running under the debugger, PyDev will try to make a reload on the existing process. In this particular case it can't find the module to reload in sys.modules and it's just warning you that the reload failed (so, it's just signalling that you have to restart the debug session in order to get those changes as it wasn't able to do a 'hot' reload).

If you don't want to use that feature, you can disable it in the preferences > pydev > debug > 'when file is changed automatically reload'.